# Swift: Video and image player (pager)

Tags: ios, swift, video-player

I work on an iOS app that bring videos and images from server, each object have many images and videos, I need to show these images and videos in a slider (pager) where user can slide to get the next one, and I need these videos and images cached in device, I google that and I found this [pod](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Lightbox) but it not play video which is a few seconds infinitely, and I try to play the provided video URL in example of pod and it's also have the same issue, are there any alternative solution or any solution for this pod?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a `UIView` outlet for display image or Video then you can use this code `
            let avPlayer  = AVPlayer()

```
        let videolink = (videosString[indexPath.row] as? String)!
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: videolink)

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: cell.videoview.frame.origin.x, y: cell.videoview.frame.origin.x, width:  cell.videoview.frame.size.width, height: cell.videoview.frame.size.height)
        cell.videoview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        avPlayer.play()`
```

like videoVideo is a view where you wish to play a video(avplayer will add a layer to that view)
To present Image, you can use `SKPhotoBrowser`

to differentiate Image and Video you can use bool
Hope you got it
If you need any help ask me i can code for you

Comment: Many thanx bro,
Can you provide me with a complete example?

Comment: sorry Ali did you fix it or not actually, I was stuck at my project at that time now I m free

Comment: let me know if need any help

Comment: Thanks for your time, but really i need a same view to show a video and Images, according to data list which contain links (urls) to both of them.

Comment: Can i c ur project or i have to use my own?

Comment: Use your own project if u can